# How to group nested list by first,last element differences in Python?

Tags: python

I need to group nested lists by first element and last element differences.

I have a nested list like :

```
[[1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 3],  [2, 17, 3]]
```

This is my code :

This creates dict and checks first and last element not in dict. If first and last element not in dict, saves list to dict.

```
b = [[1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 3],  [2, 17, 3]]
d = {}

for l in b:
    if l[2] not in d and l[0] not in d:
        d[l[2]] = [l[0],l[1],l[2]]

res = list(d.values())

print(res)
```

This returns :

```
[[1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 3]]
```

It should have returned different lists (first,last element be different). Returned lists last elements are different but first elements are same.

If the code worked properly it would have returned [**1**,17,**4**],[**2**,17,**3**]. (I marked the differences in bold.)

I need to first and last elements be different. But why this code not working properly ?

Comment: if there was `[3,17,3]` in `b`, should it be returned or not?

Comment: [3,17,3] the same 3 in the list is not problem for me. Can you elaborate the question ?

Comment: It wasn't a good example. Let's try again. If `[3,17,5]` were also in `b`, should it be kept or not? 3 already exists in `d` in your definition but it's at the front not as a last element here.

Comment: Should it be kept, because if we look at `[3,17,5]` if first element 3 not in other lists and last element 5 not in other lists no problem. `[3,17,5]` is unique. One more example : if first element 3 exists in other lists and last element 5 doesn't exist no problem.

Comment: wait, so if `b=[[3,17,1],[3,17,2]]`, the expected result is `[[3,17,1],[3,17,2]]`?

Comment: Yes. I'm so sorry for my complicated question. The logic is simple but I agree that my question is complicated and could be explained better

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `[2, 17, 3]` never gets picked up because 3 is already in `d` after `[1, 17, 3]` is added.

Here's one approach that may work. Keep a dictionary that keeps track of what elements were in first and last places in sublists and only append sublists that don't have already existing first or last elements:

```
taken = {'first':set(), 'last':set()}
d = {}
for l in b:
    if l[2] not in taken['last']:
        taken['last'].add(l[2])
        d[l[2]] = l
    else:
        if l[0] not in taken['first']:
            taken['first'].add(l[0])
            d[l[2]] = l
out = list(d.values())
```

Output:

```
[[1, 17, 4], [2, 17, 3]]
```

Comment: @skipsbiceps please see the edit and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to filter sublists to ensure the first and last element is unique relative to the previous sublists.

You could use sets to keep track of the seen values:

```
b = [[1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 3],  [2, 17, 3]]

first = set()
last  = set()

out = []
for x in b:
    if x[0] not in first and x[-1] not in last:
        out.append(x)
        first.add(x[0])
        last.add(x[-1])
```

Output: `[[1, 17, 4], [2, 17, 3]]`

Comment: code works succesfully but suppose `b` is `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]`. `[5,17,3]` and `[2,17,3]` last elements are same. In this case code returns `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3]]`. I need a unique first,last elements in list. I tried the change this code but i didn't.

Comment: @skipsbiceps I don't get your issue. What should be the output for `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]`? And why? `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3]]` matches the requirements, no?

Comment: I'm so sorry for my mixed question. `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]` in this problem `[5,17,3], [2,17,3]` should not be returned, because last elements are same. If list was `[[1,17,4],[5,17,3], [2,17,5]]`, then should be return `[1,17,4],[5,17,3], [2,17,5]` . Because in this nested list `[[1,17,4],[5,17,3], [2,17,5]]` all the first and last elements are different.

Comment: Then why in your original example `[[1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 3],  [2, 17, 3]]`, the output is `[[1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 3]]`? You also have the two 3 last

Comment: As i said, it output is wrong. It should be like your code result `[[1, 17, 4], [2, 17, 3]]`.
If i change the nested list like `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]` the output is `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3]]` but output should be like `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]` as i said the top.

Comment: I meant to type `[[1, 17, 4], [2, 17, 3]]`. Sorry but your explanations are not clear to me. Can you provide examples for which my code fails? It doesn't make sense to output `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]` according to your rule. There is a duplicate 3 in last position.

Comment: Do you want to handle first and last differently?

Comment: x[-1] in for loop going like 3-3-4 if list is `[[1, 17, 4], [5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]`. 

`[5, 17, 3], [2, 17, 3]]`` should be deleted because last elements are same.

Comment: if I put a list instead of a set and measure its length, I will probably understand that 3 is more than one and I will delete the lists whose last element is the same.

Comment: No, you confuse `x[-1]` (last element, here identical to `x[2]`) and `x[::-1]` (reversed list). I believe my code is doing exactly what you requested

Comment: Of course if you have a list like `[a,b,c,d...]` and want to consider a and c, replace my `-1` with `2`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Only i want is to delete lists with the same last element. I'm trying to do that right now.

Comment: Your code works correctly according to my request. But I asked the question incorrectly.

Comment: If you only want to consider the last element, remove the condition on first...